# MVC Passing JSON to controller with second model

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

How would I pass the model LOs in : data: JSON.stringify(LOs) - (this code does not work)?

Here is the model:

```
public class MainLoanOrderModel
{
     public LoanOrder LO { get; set; }
     public LOsBorrower LOs { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the View:

```
        @model Intranet.Models.MainLoanOrderModel
        $(function () {
        $("#add_borrower").click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: '/Loan/GetsBorrower',
                data: JSON.stringify(LOs),
                //data: { loanID: $("#LoanID").val(), fname: $("#sfname").val() },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#S_Borrower").html(data); // HTML DOM replac
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult GetsBorrower(LOs newLoanOrder)
{
        db.LOsBorrowers.Add(newLoanOrder);
        db.SaveChanges();

    return PartialView("_S_Borrower");
}
```

Comment: Can you show /Loan/GetsBorrower action pls? and what means this code does not work

Comment: I can     data: JSON.stringify(LOs), and wondering where is LOs defined?

Comment: From public LOsBorrower LOs { get; set; } , right?